# I am trying to make an input case insensitive, can someone explain how to do that?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I'm making a simple CLI in Ruby and I'm having the user to input a "Y" or "N" but right now the program is only working if they type this in upper case. I'd like it to work regardless of case. I tried using `"N".casecmp` or `"Y".casecmp` but that is giving me an argument error. Any ideas? Do I need to `require` something in environment?

Maybe showing my code would help?

```
 if input == "Y"
    method_a
 elsif input == "N"
```

Adding `.casecmp?` or `.casecmp` either sends me in an infinite loop or gives me an argument error.

Comment: `"N".casecmp?("n")`

Comment: I would typically do this by upcasing (or lower casing) the input for comparison. Would that work?

Comment: "that is giving me an argument error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What is the *precise* error message? *How* did you try "`"N".casecmp` or `"Y".casecmp`"? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method of string `downcase` and you can forget the problem of uppercase, so u can check for `y` or `n` now.

Doc: https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/downcase

Example:

```
"hEllO".downcase   #=> "hello"
```

Comment: ```.downcase``` causes an error now if the user types the input in uppercase.  ```"N".casecmp?("n")``` put me in an infinite loop for some reason. Is there a way to allow two input options? one for ```"Y"``` and one for ```"y"```

Answer (score 1):

Should work with `casecmp?` without explicitly mutating original string

[String.casecmp?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F)

> Returns true if self and other_string are equal after Unicode case
> folding, otherwise false:

```
given = "Hello"
expected = "hello"

ok = given.casecmp?(expected)

puts ok ? "Ok" : "Not" # => "Ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think between 'y' or 'Y' input have their own object_id.

So they are actually different object.

So i think it's not about the input, this is about what we gonna do from the input.

If you try to make comparison to your input regardless their case, casecmp should do the trick

```ruby
a = gets.to_s

if a.casecmp('Y').zero?
 # do stuff
elsif a.casecmp('N').zero?
 # do stuff
else
 # do stuff
end
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/String/casecmp

```ruby
'y'.casecmp('Y').zero? # true, then it is same regardless case
'Y'.casecmp('y').zero? # true
```